# Angular reactive form localpath field must allow at least two slashes - whatever the path pattern is I want exact regex pattern for localhost://4200

Tags: angular, angularjs

I have tried my reg exp but it is not working. I want this regex to have at least two slashes:

```
<div
  class="validations"
  *ngIf="dropboxForm.get('localPath')?.hasError('pattern')"
>
  <p>special characters allowed</p>
</div>
```

ts file

```
localPath: new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ][/]{2,}+$'),
]),
```

Comment: Consider building and testing your regexp [on a test website](https://regex101.com/) before transferring it to your code.

Comment: i didnot get exact regex exp for my requirement please suggest anything

Comment: Please add to your question a few example string that should match the regex. You can [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74947207/edit) using this link.

Comment: Please take care with spelling here. "At least" is two words. The personal pronoun "I" uses a capital letter, no exceptions. You can expect to be downvoted here if you use Stack Overflow like a chatroom.

Comment: at least spelling i have written correctly check once

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts file, Use escape character '\' for '/' as `^[a-zA-Z ][\/]{2,}+$`

Comment: when i tried to save ts file only one slash is saved ^[a-zA-Z ][\]{2,}+$ its not working